# Mostrar y Ocultar texto en varios elementos de la misma clase

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo ese codigo pero no me funciona alguien me puede ayudar?
[image: Javascript]
[image: HTML]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bienvenido a la comunidad.

"getElementByClassName" te devuelve un array con todos los elementos de esa calse, así que para editarlos, debes recorrer ese array.

Intenta con algo como esto

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('info-mas');

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].style.display= "none";
}
```

También te recomiendo que cuando hagas una pregunta, publique tu código como texto y no como imagen; así podemos ayudarte más fácil.

Espero te sirva, puedes ver un ejemplo aqui
https://plnkr.co/edit/BI3fAcdXzOckvVmEjiwF?p=preview

Comment: Si funciona pero tengo un problema como son varios items ma function  les aplica a todos es decir todos muestran el texto como podria evitar eso?

Comment: Quisiera que solo el boton del item que se toca mostrara mas y no todos la verdad soy super nuevo en esto de html css y javascript asi que agradecería mucho la ayuda.

Comment: Si quieres hacer algo específico lo mejor es usar ID en lugar de CLASS algo así document.getElementById('divId'); y cada Div tiene que tener un ID unico